# Complex nomenclature entries in LyX

Tags: lyx, nomenclature

When I try to make a particularly complex nomenclature entry - in particular, inserting curly braces, and in specific, `$E_{\left(A_i|B_I\right)}$` - the result simply doesn't appear in when the nomenclature entry later in the document. Everything else works fine - subscripts included, it's just the braces that seem to be broken.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) You should type `\{` and `\}` instead of just `{` and `}` to generate curly braces. Separately, you may also want to consider typing `\mid ` instead of `|` to denote the "conditional on" or "given that" relational operator. Using `\mid ` (note the space after "mid") will give you much better spacing.

Comment: `\mid` is a good idea, I'll do that. In the former case, though, I don't want visible curly braces - I just want to have the entire `\left(A_i|B_i\right)` in the subscript. (Also, LyX yells at me if I try to leave them out, and if I escape the curly braces then as expected only the left curly brace is in the subscript.)

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification. Please post a complete MWE (minimum working example -- something that starts with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`) that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

Comment: You don't need `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @Mico Um, how do I do that? I'm afraid I'm not actually working with the LaTeX here, I'm working with LyX, and I don't know how to get at the underlying code...

Comment: @egreg I do if I want the parenthesis to be scaled properly, and they don't affect whether or not the entry is displayed, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please see the posting [I've just been asked to write a minimal example. What's that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) for advice on posting an MWE. LyX is a front-end to LaTeX; you should be able to open the file created/edited in LyX in an regular text editor.

Comment: @linkhyrule5 please post a .lyx minimal example. .lyx is just a text file so open it up, copy, and paste in here. Note that LyX uses a different format than LaTeX (although LyX is able to _export_ to LaTeX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mico's suggestion to use `\mid` instead of `|` is not only for style but will fix your problem:

```
$E_{\left(A_i\mid B_I\right)}$
```

EDIT: as egreg notes, `\left(` and `\right)` do nothing as far as LaTeX is concerned here and in some cases they can add an unwanted space. I leave them here because that's what the OP has. Note that LyX renders the corresponding math differently (the `left(` and `\right)` parentheses are larger in LyX).

output:

[image]

Here is an MWE .lyx file:

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command makeindex -g
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mathdots 1
\use_mhchem 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset nomenclature
LatexCommand nomenclature
symbol "$E_{\\left(A_i\\mid B_I\\right)}$"
description "description..."

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset nomencl_print
LatexCommand printnomenclature
set_width "auto"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

And exported to LaTeX (pdflatex):

```
%% LyX 2.1.0dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$E_{\left(A_i\mid B_I\right)}$}{description...}

\settowidth{\nomlabelwidth}{$E_{\left(A_i\mid B_I\right)}$}
\printnomenclature{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should tell me what `\left` and `\right` are doing. In this case nothing at all, in other cases they add an unwanted space (and do nothing to the delimiters).

Comment: That did it. Do you know why?

Comment: @linkhyrule5 I'm not sure if this is related, but a search of the [manual](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/nomencl.pdf) for "|" gives that 'German users who want to use the shortcut notation "a instead of \"a have to redefine the quote character in nomencl.ist to something other than " (and |, @, !)'